# Forio contour remove data from bar chart (if I have duplicate label)

Tags: javascript, bar-chart, forio-contour

I need to build barchart with this data.

```
var data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
```

and labels for this data - for January in format "month, year" - for all other months - format "month".

```
var labels = ['Jan 14', 'Apr', 'Oct', 'Dec', 'Jan 15', 'Apr', 'Oct', 'Dec']
```

I added code for building chart

```
new Contour({
      el: '#bar-chart-months',
      xAxis: {
        title: 'Months',
        categories: labels
      }
    })
    .cartesian()
    .column(data)
    .render();
```

And data from duplicated labels was removed. I have only one first value for months, which are duplicated.

Off course If I add year (or another text, which do these label unique) - it works. But I don't need to do this.

Example on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/n11m84me/)

I found one dirty trick - add different count of spaces in the end of month - it works, but it's not clean.

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing that behavior in your example because you really only have two distinct categories defined and Contour is trying to assign your data values to the categories.

To achieve the effect you want (having different formatting for Jan than the rest of the months) you need to define a custom formatter for the xAxis labels in which you return the correct label depending on the category for example:

```
function (x) {
  var year = 14 + Math.floor(x/12);
  var month = x % 12;
  if (month === 0) { 
    return monthLabels[0] + ' ' + year;
  }

  return monthLabels[month];
}
```

Here's a JsFiddle with what I mean. http://jsfiddle.net/d5wqhb7p/

Hope this helps,

Jaime